# sudo: ./heartbleed-bin: command not found

Tags: kali-linux

I was trying to attack one of my virtual machines with an attack involving heartbleed-bin but this error popped up and I don't know how to resolve it. Both Kali and the victim virtual machines are using a Host-only network Adapter. How do I make the attack successful.

```
(Kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo ./heartbleed-bin -s 192.168.56.112 -p 443 -f memory.bin -t l
sudo: ./heartbleed-bin: command not found
```

Comment: this error often occurs if the binary program isn't marked executable. `chmod +x ./heartbleed-bin` might fix it in that case.

Comment: It's not the attack that is failing. Linux doesn't know how to run the command. Making this a Linux thing to sort out, not a security thing.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld ./heartbleed-bin`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question and the ip addresses you gave I assume you are working through the same book as me (page 233). I had the same problem and as mentioned by Rory, you need to change the permission then it should work fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).